# Rest-Assured and Hamcrest matchers not working with comparing arrays of ints

Tags: java, arrays, assert, rest-assured, hamcrest

With Rest Assured i'm parcing rest-response and comparing arrays.

Response body:

```
{
"error": {
    "errorObjects": [
        {
            "risks": [
                {
                    "description": "Risk1",
                    "riskId": 6654152
                },
                {
                    "description": "Risk2",
                    "riskId": 6654155
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Arrays with expected data:

```
int[] riskId = {6654152, 6654155}
String[] description =  {"Risk1",  "Risk2"}
```

Rest Assured and Hamcrest Matchers asserts:

```
.body("error.errorObjects[0].risks.description", containsInRelativeOrder(description),
                        "error.errorObjects[0].risks.riskId",containsInRelativeOrder(riskId));
```

I'm getting an error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path error.errorObjects[0].risks.riskId doesn't match.
Expected: ((a collection containing [<6654152>, <6654155>]))
  Actual: <[6654152, 6654155]>
```

So it seems that it's ok with comparing array of strings but with ints it goes mad. Help me out, maybe i need to use there another matcher, not containsInRelativeOrder? I've tried many of them but anyway getting this error